# How do I update a counter when the sensor value has exceeded a certain value?

Tags: android, sensors

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {        
     if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
         y = (int) Math.sqrt((event.values[0]*event.values[0]) + 
                   (vent.values[1]*event.values[1]) + 
                   (event.values[2]*event.values[2]));

         if (y > maxval) {
            count++;
            tv1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
         }
     }
}
```

Now, obviously count increments when sensor reading changes and y becomes > maxval. This is undesirable as count increases even when y>maxval and sensor value just changes, like consider maxval = 100. Count increases when y>100, okay. But it also increases when y value changes from 100 to 101 etc

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try to put a boolean flag like `didCount = true/false` when you do the first `count++`, then in your if condition put also this flag, and reset the flag when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of where it previously was if you want it to only fire once it goes over maxval. Something like this should work.

```
int lastVal = 0;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {        
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        y=(int)Math.sqrt((event.values[0]*event.values[0])+(event.values[1]*event.values[1])+(event.values[2]*event.values[2]));

        if(y>maxval && lastVal <= maxval){
            count++;
            tv1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        }
        lastVal = y;
    }
}
```